# Drag and drop open csv in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, drag-and-drop

The current process for opening a csv file in Google Sheets is cumbersome.

Open Google Sheets > New Document > File > Import > Upload Tab > Drag in File > Select 'Replace current sheet'

Would love a process, plugin, or single use site where I can just drag and drop a file and have it open in Google Sheets. Is that available or possible?

Answer (score 4):

The process you are describing is not necessary: Google Drive already supports drag and drop. If you have "Convert Uploads" enabled in Google Drive settings, then all you need is to:

1. Open Google Drive.
2. Drag-and-drop a CSV file to the page.
3. Double-click to open.

If you **don't** have "Convert Uploads" enabled, then it's still 3 steps:

1. Open Google Drive.
2. Drag-and-drop a CSV file to the page.
3. Right-click and choose "Open with Google Sheets" (this creates a copy of the file in Sheets format, and opens it)

Comment: But if you already have a sheet open, the drive shortcut doesn't work as well